# Hadoop error when using spark-submit

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, spark-ec2

I am trying to spark-submit using Amazon ec2 with the following:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1 --master spark://amazonaws.com SimpleApp.py
```

and I end up with the following error. It seems to be that it is looking for hadoop. My ec2 cluster was created using spark-ec2 command.

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/adas/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/adas/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/adas/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 66439ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
    :: modules in use:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1

    ==== local-m2-cache: tried

      file:/home/adas/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.pom

      -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1!hadoop-aws.jar:

      file:/home/adas/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar

    ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

      /home/adas/.ivy2/local/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/ivys/ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1!hadoop-aws.jar:

      /home/adas/.ivy2/local/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/jars/hadoop-aws.jar

    ==== central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.pom

      -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1!hadoop-aws.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar

    ==== spark-packages: tried

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.pom

      -- artifact org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1!hadoop-aws.jar:

      http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.pom (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable))

    Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable))

    Server access error at url http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.pom (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable))

    Server access error at url http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable))


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-aws;2.7.1: not found]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1078)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Is your server connected to the internet..?

Comment: @BruceWayne, unfortunately I cannot allow my spark master to have access to the internet. Do you know how I can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, it was just some local proxy issues.

Comment: I thin you have to accept the above answer as it is pointing to same proxy issue, rather creating new answer and accepting your own...

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting the job with `--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1` option and job is attempting to resolve the dependencies by downloading the packages from public maven repo. However, this error indicates it's unable to reach the maven repo.

```
Server access error at url https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.7.1/hadoop-aws-2.7.1.pom (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable))
```

You might want to check if the spark master has access to internet.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot allow my spark master to have access to the internet. Do you know how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: spark-submit accepts another option `--jars` which accepts 3rd party jar location on your driver. Every jar provided by this option, will be transferred to workers.